# object has no attribute chercher_canal

Tags: python, object, error-handling, attributes

hi im getting this error when trying my code:
Any help apreciated thx

> File "C:\Users\miky.DESKTOP-70ENDO8\Google Drive\TP2 Programmation orientée objet\TP2_V3\distributeur.py", line 90, in creer_forfait_tv
>       canal = p_poste.chercher_canal()
>   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'chercher_canal'

THE CODE ITSELF:

```
from canal import Canal
from forfait_tv import ForfaitTV
from abonne import Abonne

class Distributeur:
#-----------  Constructeur -----------------------------
def __init__(self):
    self.__canaux = None
    self.__forfaits = None
    #code
    self.__canaux = [] #list
    self.__forfaits = [] #list

#----------- Accesseurs/Mutateurs ----------------------
def ajouter_canal(self,un_canal:Canal):
    self.__canaux.append(un_canal)


def chercher_canal(self,p_poste:int):
    postex = None
    poste_trouve=None
    lstPoste = []
    for i in lstPoste:
        postex=lstPoste[i]
        if postex.get_poste()== p_poste:
            poste_trouve=postex
            return print(poste_trouve)

def telecharger_canaux(self,nom_fichier:str):

    fichierCanaux = open(nom_fichier, "r")
    for line in fichierCanaux:
        eleCanal = line.strip(" : ")
        canal = Canal(eleCanal[0],str(eleCanal[1]),str(eleCanal[2]),eleCanal[3])
        self.__canaux.append(canal)
        return canal


def sauvegarder_canaux(self, nom_fichier:str):
    canalx = None
    numeroPost = None
    fichCanaux = open(nom_fichier,"w")
    for i in self.__canaux:
        numeroPost = i.get_poste()
        nomPoste = i.get_nom()
        descPost = i.get_description()
        couexPost = i.get_cout_extra()
        fichCanaux.write(str(numeroPost)+ ":" + str(nomPoste) + ":" + str(descPost) + ":" + str(couexPost) + "\n")

    fichCanaux.close()



#----------- Opérations --------------------------------

def creer_forfait_tv(self, p_nom:str, p_coutBase:float, p_poste:list):
    forfait = ForfaitTV(p_nom,p_coutBase)
    self.__forfaits.append(forfait)
    canal = None

    for i in p_poste:
        canal = p_poste.chercher_canal()
        forfait.ajouter_canal(canal)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you call not a method `chercher_canal` in the following code, but a list attribute:

```
def creer_forfait_tv(self, p_nom:str, p_coutBase:float, p_poste:list):
    forfait = ForfaitTV(p_nom,p_coutBase)
    self.__forfaits.append(forfait)
    canal = None

    for i in p_poste:
        canal = p_poste.chercher_canal()
        forfait.ajouter_canal(canal)
```

Change the line to:
`canal = chercher_canal(p_poste)`

Also, I'm not 100% sure but maybe you want to use `i` instead of `p_poste`?